# When to create a new Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am battling to understand when I should create a new controller.

Let's say I have an application that maintains people records (Name, age etc)

I have a few views.
A view to show a list of people, which I can select to display.
A view to display detailed person information (view only)
A view to edit a person record
A view to add a person record
(Is Add and Edit usually one view, in MVC?)

At the moment, I have one controller. But is that right, or should I have a controller per view?
I'm worried my single controller is getting too big...

Comment: This is perfectly right. Person is your resource and it will have list, show, add, update and delete operations logically grouped together.

Comment: Thanks! I'd have marked this as the correct answer, if I could have.

Comment: Not a problem :) @Darin, the answering machine, anyways deserves it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to have a controller per resource (person in your case), not controller per view. So you are correct to have a `PersonsController` handling the list of persons, a person details and editing a person.